# Is the word 'mistake' a concrete or abstract noun?

Tags: countable-nouns, abstract-nouns

According to [Answers.com](https://www.answers.com/Q/Is_the_word_mistake_a_concrete_or_abstract_noun):

> The word mistake is an abstract noun, a word for an error in action or judgement.

Is this correct?

Then, why does it act like concrete nouns such as 'car' when it comes to countability?

Both 'mistake' and 'car' are countable, unless they follow "by".

> a. *I made three mistakes today.* vs. *I went there by mistake.*
>
> b. *I saw three cars today.* vs. *I went there by car.*

Does this prove that 'mistake' is also a concrete noun?
Or is 'mistake' still an abstract noun, despite this similarity in countability?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98311/discussion-on-question-by-listeneva-is-the-word-mistake-a-concrete-or-abstract).

Answer (score 19):

Being able to count (or not count) a concrete or abstract noun is not a criterion that determines its type.

---

Some concrete nouns are countable:

> ✔ Look at that *car*.
>   ✔ Look at those *cars*.

Some concrete nouns are not countable:

> ✔ Help me with my *luggage*.
>   ✘ Help me with my *luggages*.

---

Some abstract nouns are countable:

> ✔ I made a *mistake*.
>   ✔ I made a couple of *mistakes*.

Some abstract nouns are not countable:

> ✔ How much *progress* have you made?
>   ✘ How many *progresses* have you made?

Comment: You may be right that countability has nothing to do with the abstract/concrete dichotomy. But I think that countability is the only syntactic test for a noun. So if you dismiss the syntactic test, the abstract/concrete dichotomy has to be purely semantic, in which case what's the semantic criteria to distinguish abstract nouns from concrete nouns?

Comment: @listeneva - Isn't the semantic criteria just the definition of the noun(s) in question? Are there nouns whose definitions don't make it clear whether they're abstract or not?

Comment: @nnnnnn That's right. Pretty much like the *meaning* of any word, it's essentially an entirely arbitrary definition. Based on what a word has been *defined* to mean, it will may then follow certain guidelines that other words with similar types of meaning also follow. But there is no exact rule for anything.

Comment: 'Progresses'. My new favourite non-word.

Comment: It's only a non-noun. Makes a fine verb.

Comment: @listeneva Abstract v concrete is purely a semantic definition. As far as I know there is no grammatical difference between concrete and abstract nouns. (I'm prepared to be corrected on that).

Comment: @marcellothearcane If my dementia progresses, I might forget that "progresses" in indeed a real word :)

Comment: @only_pro that's a different thing

Comment: It's usually extremely unhelpful to use the term 'non-count noun' or say 'this noun is not countable'. One sense of 'progress' is certainly count [[Wiktionary sense 3](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/progress)] (and doubtless in OED). An example: [The Progresses of Henry VIII, 1509–1529: Springer-Link](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-349-24214-6_4).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It's extremely unhelpful to label one thing 'extremely unhelpful' without showing what is helpful.

Comment: "Everything is countable, preciouses" --Gollum

Comment: @listeneva Would you rather I'd said " 'Some abstract nouns are countable' followed by the exemplar 'progress'  is misleading; 'progresses' certainly exists as a plural count usage"? I at least attempt to correct reasonably unvenomously. I think this makes the sixth or seventh time I've said on ELU "Specific _usages_ of nouns, not the nouns themselves, are count or non-count." You can look up some of the _discussions_ I've been in over whether 'furniture' has a count usage

Answer (score 6):

Concrete nouns represent actual physical objects - table, paint, star, insect etc.

An abstract noun represent something that cannot be physically perceived - idea, ambition, prohibition, concept.

So yes, mistake is an abstract noun. As far as I know abstract nouns are treated exactly the same as concrete ones.

Comment: Thanks. But when you say 'I made three mistakes today', I think you can "perceive" those mistakes. Just because 'mistake' doesn't have a physical shape doesn't mean you cannot perceive it. No?

Comment: So is *vacuum* a concrete noun?

Comment: There is a grey area, and vacuum is in it. (Probably)

Comment: @listeneva: I suggest DJClayworth should re-write "cannot be actually perceived" to "cannot be physically perceived". Which clears up the distinction.

Comment: @DJClayworth: whatever a vacuum is, it is _clearly_ not a _grey_ area! ;-)

Comment: Some mistakes *can* be physically percieved though.  For example, there is a (deliberate to make a point) spelling mistake in the previous sentence.  You can see it with your eyes and point to it.  Depending on your browser, there may even be a red squiggly line underneath it.  So it can be concrete or abstract depending on context.

Comment: @NigelTouch - Sometimes a vacuum can fix a grey area; other times it takes a damp rag.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, a "mistake" can be either abstract or concrete.

> "He must have made a mistake doing that math in his head because his
>   answer's wrong."

That's clearly abstract.  The mistake is complete intangible and exists merely as an idea.

> "Those four cupcakes are mistakes. You can eat the mistakes if you
>   like, but the ones that aren't mistakes are for company."

That's clearly not abstract because you can literally pick up and eat the mistakes.

As for "mistake" being a countable noun, which it is, that has absolutely nothing to do with whether or not it's abstract or concrete. Say a bunch of quarters are on a table.  I can say, "The coins are on the table."  I can say, "The money is on the table."  In those sentences, "coin" is a count noun and concrete and "money" is a non-count noun and concrete.  They're both concrete nouns as they both indicate the exact same tangible objects lying on the table, so being concrete doesn't preclude a noun from being non-count and being a count noun does't mean a noun is necessarily concrete, as the very first example sentence above demonstrates.

Comment: I understand your point about the cupcakes, but it feels kind of borderline. Mistake or not they are still physical cupcakes, and labelling them mistakes is more conceptual. (Either way, concrete cupcakes are a mistake.)

Comment: You seem to use 'tangibility' as the only criterion to distinguish concrete and abstract nouns. But the question remains whether something is tangible or not. For example, is _information_ tangible? If you can see some information, it's tangible and thus a concrete noun, and if you only have some information in your head, it's intangible and thus an abstract noun? How about 'atmosphere'? In _The atmosphere of fear was tangible_, is _atmostphere_ or _fear_ a concrete noun because it's tangible?

Comment: Fear is a real thing, but the phrase "the atmosphere of fear is tangible" is meant figuratively, as are similar expressions about fear or dread pressing down on someone.

Comment: The cupcakes are not the mistakes but they are here due to mistakes. Countability to the rescue. How many mistakes are there if there are four cupcakes? Could be any number from one up. Made too many. So one mistake. Forgot that uncle Salisbury is allergic to nuts so had to discard three and start over and then made one too many. So two mistakes. Made one a day early, then 2 with nuts, then 1 extra. So three mistakes.  And so on.

Comment: A mistake is a relational condition involving the intent a person has and the actions they take in regard to that intent. Choosing a wrong action is a mistake. The mistake is the choice. The action is mistaken but it is not the mistake it is by mistake. So are the consequences, and so are the concretes that might result.

Comment: @puppetsock That's a nice theoretical analysis, but what to you call "something that should have been a cupcake, except it looks like a small piece of volcanic ash because I cooked it wrong". "A mistake" seems a pretty good name for it  IMO.